# Access to Path Denied Even When Run in Admin and Added In Manifest

Tags: c#

In the code below I'm searching and replacing text in a JSON file for a video game. I tested it in the bin folder and it worked fine but when it came to doing the actual file in the steam directory it would give me the Access to the path 'D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Unturned' is denied. I've tried running Visual Studio in admin mode and I've tried adding `<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` to the manifest but that didn't work (and yes I made sure to set it in my application manifest). Also, the game wasn't running either:

```
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.UnturnedPath);
        text = text.Replace("Line 1", "Replaced Value");
        File.WriteAllText("EconInfo.json", text);
    }

    private void btnSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Settings().Show();
    }
}
```

}

The actual message that pops up is below:

```
    ************** Exception Text **************
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Unturned' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path)
   at UnturnedSwapper.Form1.btnTest_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\parke\source\repos\UnturnedSwapper\Main Form.cs:line 26
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam).
```

Comment: Actually, the NTFS ACLs allow to configure access rights to prevent anyone (including admins) access files. Even file owner will not be able to access file content (but still be able to edit ACLs). So, could you please check the real permissions of desired file?

Comment: Is `D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Unturned` a file or a directory?  I ask this because Windows will give a permission-denied error attempting to perform file operations on a directory.

Comment: You can get that error if the file you are trying to change is in use by another process.

Comment: I fixed the problem finally! I forgot to specify the JSON file I was trying to edit and was trying to edit the folder directly which obviously won't work.